# Is there a way to create new user extensions with RingCentral API?

Tags: php, ringcentral

I have one RingCentral user account. I also have several users with virtual extensions --each having their own RingCentral login credentials based on their extension number.

I am constantly adding/removing users to this account. So the objective is to reduce this manual overhead. Ideally, when I add a user in our company portal, the API would create the user and extension at RingCentral. Likewise, when I deactivate the user in the company portal, the API would deactivate their account and release that extension.

I did look at the RingCentral API
https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-explorer/latest/index.html

I'm not a programmer but from what I can tell, there is no PUT or POST under "Account". The only option seems to be GET.

Also, RingCentral doesn't consider these to be actual "User Accounts" but rather "Virtual Extensions". In the API, there are POST options for Extensions, but I see nothing about creating new extensions.

Does this mean that it's not possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add User Extensions to your RingCentral Account via Service Web :

https://success.ringcentral.com/articles/RC_Knowledge_Article/5-10-Adding-Extensions-via-Web

I absolutely agree with your findings however, we do not have an API to `Create New User` Extensions at this point in time. But the good news is our Team is working on it and this feature would very soon be available via API's.

Kindly stay tuned for more updates on [RingCentral Developer Portal](https://developer.ringcentral.com/) page or on our [RingCentral Developer Community](https://devcommunity.ringcentral.com/ringcentraldev).

Comment: i am using glip post message API for adding post in glip group. Currently it takes my user name while posting. I want to use a different name of user for posting like my Bot or something like that.
How to achieve the same ? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that we can create a new user with the API, but you can definitely add virtual extensions for the existing API. you can check [this](https://support.ringcentral.com/s/article/Extensions-Create-Virtual-Extension?language=en_US) link for more info.